# Receiving 'This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.' error when adding httpModule to VS web project

Tags: asp.net

Can someone shed some light on what's going on?  I have a website created using VS 2010.  The following code is added by default by VS when adding an httpModule.  When I run the app through Casseni, the highlighted line throws the error "This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode."

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // Below is an example of how you can handle LogRequest event and provide 
        // custom logging implementation for it
       **context.LogRequest += new EventHandler(OnLogRequest);**
    }

    #endregion

    public void OnLogRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        //custom logging logic can go here
    }
```

My web.config file was updated as such:

```
<configuration>  
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

  <httpModules>
    <add name="GlobalModule" type="MyApp.Global.GlobalModule, EduCarePro"/>
  </httpModules>

</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<modules>
  <remove name="GlobalModule"/>
  <add name="GlobalModule" type="MyApp.Global.GlobalModule, EduCarePro" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there something else that must be configured in the Web.Config to prevent this error??

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that Visual Studio's development web server does not support this functionality. You must run this code on an a machine running IIS.

**TAKEN FROM (And Worked for me too as i had same problem)**

[Link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1816608.aspx/1)